# Magento 1.9.2.1 Image Upload error

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

I have the problem that I can not upload my images to the product pages. It was working before, but now it is not possible. I have tried to upload with different browsers(Firefox/Explorer/Chrome), they all have the same problem. The buttons (browse / upload) appaer and I can select my image and upload it.(It shows that it is charching.) But it does not appaer in the list of product images. I asked a friend to try to upload. With his computer it was possible to upload the images to the list.What kind of problem am I facing here? Has it to do directly with magento? Thanks for the help.
[image]

Comment: Check console log.

Comment: @pet 
Can delete the var/cache folder and check it again

Answer (score 0):

Most probable cause is some problem with Flash in your browsers version / computer. You are not alone, this a very common problem

Most solid solution would be to forget Flash & use extensions such as https://www.mavenecommerce.com/blog/magento-html5-uploader/

Comment: Explain why downvote